# Div Taking Screen Width & Height

Tags: html, css

I've been breaking my head the past two days figuring this out. Basically, i am creating a one page layout, where the first block takes the width and height of the screen and the second block needs to be relative.

Example: http://www.shegy.nazwa.pl/themeforest/exit/normal/

```
<body>

<div id = "block1">
This is block 1 taking 100% width and height of screen.
</div>

<div id="block2">
Block 2 is relative to block 1
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: What about using `width: 100vw; height: 100vh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add `height: 100%;` and `margin: 0;` to the body/html. Then it works wonders :).

## HTML:

```
<div id="box1">HELLO HELLO THIS IS RED BOX, ARE YOU HEARING ME BLUE?</div>
<div id="box2">YES, RED, I'VE GOT YOU LOUD AND CLEAR. OVER. <div>
```

## CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#box1 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

#box2 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

## FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ewzLM/1/

Comment: No, this would be a perfect example:

http://www.shegy.nazwa.pl/themeforest/exit/normal/

Comment: @Riqwan So the next page is also 100% by 100%?

Comment: Only width is 100%. Its not a page per se, but yeah.

Comment: @Riqwan Okay, I fixed my answer. Check it out! It's actually a very common technique nowadays.

Comment: You can't have multiple IDs on the same page — it has to be unique.

Comment: @Terry Not that it really matters but... Fixed.

Comment: @Terry Oh, didn't know. Anyhow, fixed and thank you.

Comment: Thanks man, i figured it out earlier, but yeah, this is pretty much what i did. Cheers!