# Setting image height to 100% of the screen on multiple resolutions

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site http://204.44.67.143/datacenter/

I want to set the big image to be 100% height of the monitor the user is viewing on, I've tried to just put height: 100%; but it was not displaying atall after that, can anyone give me a hand?

HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Welcome to WebXury</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

CSS

```
 /* Carousel base class */
 .carousel {
  height: 900px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }

 /* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
 .carousel .item {
   height: 900px;
   background-color: #777;
 }
 .carousel-inner > .item > img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   height: 900px;
 }
```

When I change the height to 100% it is not displaying atall, so am using 900px atm but as you can imagine that will not fill the whole page on some higher resolutions.

Comment: `height:100%` does not work like `width:100%` You may want to take a look at http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Comment: How about using height:inherit

Comment: height: 100vh;     <-- 100% of the viewport height.  You will then also have to edit the .carousel .item { height: 100vh;}

Comment: height: 100vh worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS for the carousel:

I have adapted your code in a test and got the image to stretch screen wide en high

```
.carousel-inner > .item  {
  position: absolute;
    background:#040;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
 }

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
       <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Welcome to WebXury</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Put the image as background and use `background-size` for CSS. You may have to go a little different about the carousel slide script, but you get your stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Check my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025122/div-taking-screen-width-height/23025166#23025166) out:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#box1 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

#box2 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">HELLO HELLO THIS IS RED BOX, ARE YOU HEARING ME BLUE?</div>
<div id="box2">YES, RED, I'VE GOT YOU LOUD AND CLEAR. OVER. <div>
```

You can apply the same thing for an image.